# japan yahoo auction my won list

Tags: yii2-advanced-app, yahoo, yahoo-api

I want to fetch my auction won list from yahoo auction website url api given below. on yahoo development website. I am not able to understand from where I need to get access token. Please check below ref site with code

ref site : https://developer.yahoo.co.jp/webapi/auctions/auction/v2/mywonlist.html

```
https://auctions.yahooapis.jp/AuctionWebService/V2/myWonList?start=>
Sample request
GET /AuctionWebService/V2/myWonList?start=
Host: auctions.yahooapis.jp
Authorization: Bearer <Token>
```

I am using yii2. I have already used other apis like listing categories with listing auctions and searching and all and everything working fine but how can I access or use these api.

```
My auction display (watch list · auction underway)
My auction display (watch list · ended auction)
My auction display (during bidding)
My auction display (successful bid portion)
My auction display (under exhibition)
My auction display (exhibition end minute)
My auction display (successful bidder list)
My auction deletion (successful bid part)
My auction deletion (exhibition end minute)
My auction display (price cut negotiation)
```

as these above mentioned all api's required access token but how can I get the access token.

Answer (score 0):

You need to follow certain steps to get access token.
The steps can be found in [this page](https://developer.yahoo.co.jp/yconnect/v2/)(do note all the documents are in Japanese). Those steps are:

1. Read T&Cs.
2. Get YahooID.
3. Get ClientID(and the secret).
4. Deploy your application with those information.

It depends on what you need to achieve, but you have a few options to get the access token. And from your description I assume your app will require what YahooJapan calls "Authorization Code Flow", which you can find [here](https://developer.yahoo.co.jp/yconnect/v2/authorization_code/).

Hope it helps.

[image]